# Dynamic Array of char Pointer

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to define a dynamic array containing char pointers that point to strings. The string can be of any length, so i used char pointers. I want to dynamically resize the array each time I need to store more values. The following code gives me segmentation fault. Am I doing it well?

```
int main() {
    char **input=NULL;
    char *buffer;

    int i=0;

    do {
        input = (char **)realloc(input, (i+1) * sizeof(char *));

        scanf("%s", &buffer);
        strcpy(input[i++],buffer);

    } while(strlen(buffer)!=0);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your buffer and your input[i] are not allocated.

Answer (score 8):

There are multiple issues in your code. It won't work until you fix all of them

- You aren't allocating memory for `buffer`. Scanf would write into thin air, if it weren't for the next point which is arguably more serious
- You should pass `buffer` to scanf, **not `&buffer`**
- You aren't allocating memory for `input[i]`. You are only allocating
  memory for `input`.

Answer (score 1):

buffer is uninitialized. Besides &buffer is a pointer to a pointer, not to a character array, as you probably intend.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you define `buffer` as a pointer, but you do not point it to something that can hold the scanned string, so `scanf` writes out in unallocated memory which is really bad. You also do not allocate `input[i]` so `strcpy` will also fail. You might want to change that to use `strdup` instead:

```
input[i++] = strdup(buffer);
```

Another couple of nitpicks: When scanning for a string, you do not need the `&` on the string buffer, so redo like this:

```
scanf("%s", buffer);
```

And you should not cast the result of `realloc` (or `malloc` either for that matter):

```
input = realloc(input, (i+1) * sizeof(char *));
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the issues already listed in the other answers the loop will never terminate as:

```
scanf("%s", buffer);
```

will not return until it reads at least one character, excluding the end of line character.